# How to know if I'm flag-hellbanned?

Tags: discussion, flagging

With the change in the Late Answers review queue, I've found myself hellbanned for flagging suspicious but old spam-like activity. I would like to know if I'm indeed flagbanned to Hell.

> Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!

- [how to restore cloud site on rackspace from files container](https://serverfault.com/questions/536126/how-to-restore-cloud-site-on-rackspace-from-files-container/536784#536784) - declined
- [Backup solutions for Rackspace cloud sites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/95353/backup-solutions-for-rackspace-cloud-sites/536827#536827) - helpful
- [Backup solutions for Rackspace cloud sites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/95353/backup-solutions-for-rackspace-cloud-sites/536124#536124) - declined

Some of older flags were declined but the underlying posts were eventually deleted:

- [How to run node.js app on port 80? Are processes blocking my port?](https://serverfault.com/questions/602240/how-to-run-node-js-app-on-port-80-are-processes-blocking-my-port/710310#710310)
- [How to setup shared folder as virtual directory in IIS 7.5 (cross-domain)](https://serverfault.com/questions/488965/how-to-setup-shared-folder-as-virtual-directory-in-iis-7-5-cross-domain/694540#694540)
- [VMware Linux Server -- how can you tell if you are a vm or real hardware?](https://serverfault.com/questions/65718/vmware-linux-server-how-can-you-tell-if-you-are-a-vm-or-real-hardware/685763#685763)
- [OpenVPN restriction](https://serverfault.com/questions/146690/openvpn-restriction/683689#683689)
- [How do I Verify installation requirements for Maximo 7.5 Installation?](https://serverfault.com/questions/679897/how-do-i-verify-installation-requirements-for-maximo-7-5-installation/680838#680838)
- [eth0 NIC Link is Down repeating message in kernel log](https://serverfault.com/questions/585442/eth0-nic-link-is-down-repeating-message-in-kernel-log/675084#675084)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/189912

Comment: @MichaelHampton - so it's a week-long ban. Okay, thanks.

Comment: As an aside, I think I would have declined most of those flags too. Those zipitbackup posts don't appear to be spam to me. See also http://serverfault.com/help/promotion and http://serverfault.com/help/product-support

Comment: @MichaelHampton -  I see your point. What intrigued me at the time was the coincidence between the two users, asking and answering q's on one product only. Was puzzled why one of the spam flags got marked helpful but all others did not.

Comment: I don't know. I wasn't the moderator who handled them.

Comment: Yeah, IMHO, standards on the site have changed enough that the older posts are hard.  "How do I do X?"  "Here's a link to a GREAT PRODUCT that does Y!"  Uhhhh.  Skip.  And wince.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the ban consigned me to Limbo, and only for a week.